# Simulink Linear Analysis Pole/Zero Plots

Tags: plot, simulink

[Here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiLvi08ZlJGcif407D_o8rrmwXfNZg) is the Simulink file I'm having problems with. I have this system controlled by a PID controller which gives me the desired response on 'Scope1'. Now I want to do some plots using "Analysis -> Control Design -> Linear Analysis...".

Here I get my bode and step responses plot, but when I go to the "I/O Pole/Zero Map" all the poles and zeros are on the right side (real positive values) which means the system is unstable and it seems to be contradictory from the step and bode plot that shows an stable system. Am I missing or misinterpreting anything? Here are the bode and step plots I get:

[image]

[image]

And this is the I/O Pole/Zero Map:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my bad, on discrete systems, if the poles/zeros are inside the circumference the system is stable.